# Std. HTML: Why is page jump to <a id="name"> displaying the top of the linked page?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, anchor

I've read other stackoverflow threads on this topic, but they relate to using scripts..... but my application is a standard HTML link.
I have a link on page 2.

```
<a href="page1.html#paragraph3"><h6>click here: to view paragraph 3 on page 1.</h6></a>
```

The anchor on page 1. =

```
<a id="paragraph3"></a>
```

Within the page, this link works.
However, from a different page, the chosen section displays for a millisecond, and the page jumps to the top.

Why is this happening, and how should I be constructing the link, for it to jump correctly?

**Javascript in Use**

```
<!-- ============ Navigation Bar ============= -->
<div id='output1'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--  
document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = menunav+home+info+infosub+doit+blog+lang+contact;
// End  -->
</script>
<!-- ============ //End of Navigation Bar ============ -->
```

**Scroll to top (activated by a floating arrow icon)**

```
jQuery(function($) {'use strict';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},200);
});
});
```

**Smooth Scrolling**

```
/*  <!--smooth-scrolling-of-move-up-->*/
$(document).ready(function() {
/*  var defaults = {
containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
scrollSpeed: 1200,
easingType: 'linear'
};  */
$().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
});
```

**I believe that is all the relevant code.**

Having copied and pasted it, I'm wondering if it is the writing of the navbar.
But it is called right at the top of the page.... so I'm not sure.

Comment: Show us a minimal example exhibiting this behaviour.

Comment: Are you using wordpress or any other content management system? Most likely some piece of Javascript is causing the issue. Like a drop down menu or something.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly JavaScript or a random plugin. HTML loads first and then JavaScript is executed. Thus when the HTML loads you are taken to the correct place. But as JS or plugins load they probably restructure the page and then pull you back to the top so that you don't notice that in restructuring the page they made a mess first.

Comment: Thanks everybody - I was suspecting this may be related to add on JS.
I'll edit the question, so perhaps we can pinpoint it.

Comment: Just re-reading the comments: "HTML loads first and then Javascript".... hmmm!.... it looks like 'having the benefit of a single cross site navbar code' has its drawbacks..... maybe I need to load the page, and then call a script to move to the required para.

Comment: So do we think it is the written navbar that is causing the problems?.... If so I can write the answer to the question........ it could be helpful to people.

Comment: I have just deleted all the javascript from the page, and smooth scrolling from the js file..... the problem persists..... hmmm!..... a mystery.